# WPF Datagrid - DataGridTextColumn ObservableCollection1 error

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have the followin error in my XAML code, and i have no idea how to fix it.

on MouseOver says in the Tooltip:

> A value of Type 'DataGridTExtColumn' cannot be added to a collection or dictionary of type 'ObservableCollection`1'.

Here is a Screenshot:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GyYpE.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It just resolved it self.

I've rebuild, saved and then restarted VS, and the error disappeared.